# When using alias in NGiNX is the content of the file called loaded on the RAM?

Tags: nginx, memory, memory-usage

When I load a static file via alias does it load the whole file into the RAM and then sends it to the user or is it stream directly to the user?

I am wandering because I have a server with 250MB of RAM and I was wandering what would happen if I use alias in NGiNX to get a static file that was 250MB or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is streamed directly to the user. People are running servers with 1 GB of ram and serving files with gigabytes in size for hundreds of users simultaneously.

Comment: Absolutely correct. This is why returning the X-accel header from cgi is so much better than loading the resource and sending it to the client from the cgi. It should be noted that the operating system will try to cache as much of the disk read as it can, which greatly helps if a lot of users are grabbing the same file.

Comment: Yeah, there are hundreds of caching mechanisms, some on os level, some on webserver level etc :)

Comment: given enough ram, the os-cache is as fast as serving (static|cached) content directly from ram-mounted TMPFS.